# First Order Difference Equations - Using Eigenvectors/Values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations

I was reading some notes and there was the following section:

> Start with a given vector $\vec{u}_0$. We can create a sequence of vectors in which each
> new vector is $A$ times the previous vector: $$\vec{u}_{k+1} = A\vec{u}_k$$
> $\vec{u}_{k+1} = A\vec{u}_k$ is a first order difference equation, and $\vec{u}_{k} = A^k\vec{u}_0$ is a solution to this system.
> We get a more satisfying solution if we write $\vec{u}_0$ as a combination of eigenvectors of $A$:
> $$\vec{u}_0 = c_1\vec{x}_1 + c_2\vec{x}_2 + · · · + c_n\vec{x}_n = S\vec{c}$$
> Then:
> $$A\vec{u}_0 = c_1\lambda_1\vec{x}_1 + c_2\lambda_2\vec{x}_2 + · · · + c_n\lambda_n\vec{x}_n$$
> and:
> $$\vec{u}_k=A^k\vec{u}_0=c_1\lambda_1^k\vec{x}_1 + c_2\lambda_2^k\vec{x}_2 + · · · + c_n\lambda_n^k\vec{x}_n=\Lambda^kS\vec{c}$$
> (Here $S$ represents the matrix $S=[\vec{x}_1\quad \vec{x}_2\quad ...\quad \vec{x}_n]$, the matrix with the eigenvectors of $A$ as columns, and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with its non-zero entries being the eigenvalues of $A$.)

They later apply this to get a closed form equation for the $k$-th Fibonacci number, and the formula they get is correct, however on the last line of the excerpt I don't see why they get
$$\vec{u}_k=\Lambda^kS\vec{c} \qquad (1)$$
instead of
$$\vec{u}_k=S\Lambda^k\vec{c} \qquad (2)$$
Specifically because I don't see how using $(1)$ will get you that same summation as in the last line in the excerpt, which $(1)$ aims to compact. Moreover, if you assume $A$ has $n$ independent eigenvectors then using $A^k=S\Lambda^k S^{-1}$ you get
$$\vec{u}_k=A^k\vec{u}_0=A^kS\vec{c}=S\Lambda^k S^{-1}S\vec{c}=S\Lambda^k\vec{c}$$
which is $(2)$, which is what I believe the matrix notation of that long summation would be.

Comment: For now I am going to assume the notes are incorrect, but any conformation regarding my reasoning would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a new coefficient vector 
$$\eqalign{
 \vec{b} &= \Lambda^k\,\vec{c} \cr
}$$
or in component form
$$\eqalign{
 b_j &= \lambda^k_j\,c_j \cr\cr
}$$
The $u$-vectors can be expressed in terms of the $S$-matrix as 
$$\eqalign{
 \vec{u_0} &= S\vec{c} \cr
 \vec{u_k} &= S\vec{b} = S\Lambda^k\vec{c} \cr 
}$$